# iPhone: Can I get an image picker to have the documents folder as its source

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

It looks like I cant create an album for my picture producing app in the photo library... so what I was going to do is save the images to the documents folder for my app, which I think should be easy enough.  The issue though is that the image picker seems to only allow you to pick saved images or photo library as the source, and I would like users to be able to view all images created by my app.  Is there a way to make the picker work or will I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image picker that apple provides only gives you access to pictures saved in the camera roll.  It also gives you the functionality to take a new picture if you are on an iphone.  If you save pictures in your app's local storage directory, then you need to build your own mechanism for viewing these photos.  You may want to take a look at Joe Hewitt's [320 project](http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/) - it has a lot of good controls that you may find useful.